# Kohana 3.3 не находит хэлпер

Tags: php, kohana

Создал файл Mail.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Mail{

    public static function send($to,$from, $subject,$text){
        $message = View::factory('mail');
        $message->bind('e_m', $e_m);
        $message->bind('t_m', $text);
        $code = Email::send('default',$subject, $message, $from, $to);
    }
}
```

Вызываю Mail::send(тут парамметры!);
Он мне говорит что Mail не найден!

Comment: Простите, в коде у вас напиасно Email::send, а ниже вы пишете, что вызываете Mail::send

Comment: Email::send - это модуль!
А Mail::send - это хэлпер! Как видите я здесь отпускаю один параметр по умолчанию! И Выстраиваю параметры в нужном мне порядке!

Answer (score 1):

Если файл лежит в корне каталога Classes, то всё должно работать

Comment: уже и в корень ложил, и уже отдельную папку helpers создавал

Comment: положите файл в APPPATH\Classes\Mail.php и всё у вас будет работать